# SQL Server trigger - the same SQL query is slower when inside a trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers

One of my database trigger is taking **45 seconds** to execute (I'm timing it by inserting the trigger starting time and ending time in another table, within the code of the trigger, so I'm pretty confident it's not a measurement issue).

But when I execute the same query as the one of the trigger (on the same environment, with the same data), the executing time is now **3 seconds**.

Any idea what could explain and how to investigate such disparity in the execution time, for the same query within a trigger and outside a trigger? (The trigger and the query run on `AFTER INSERT` and process/insert some rows in another separate table)

TL,DR: why is my trigger slow but the same query fast?

Comment: Depends entirely on what it does, and on what actions the trigger runs. Can you post the code of each, hopefully with schema of database objects it touches?

Comment: @Bridge I can't, for NDA reasons. But I'm more looking for possible leads on why a trigger wouldn't take the same time to execute as the same query.

Comment: OK - it's guesswork then. When does the trigger run? Insert, update, delete? Could whichever of those causes the trigger to run make it get run more than once?

Comment: You could put some `PRINT` commands in your script to verify how many times a certain part of the code is being executed. Like Bridge said, maybe some parts are getting executed more than once when it is in the trigger. You might want to `PRINT` the value of the variables to in order to verify they are the value you expect.

Comment: run sp_who2 to search for blocking queries

Comment: First, please see this article wrote by Erland Sommarskog: [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS? ](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html). Second, if you want detailed info/help you should publish the source code and also the actual execution plan (SSMS > Ctrl + M > F5) for both cases.

Comment: Could you solve this problem? I have a similar one. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/245446/scan-on-trigger-seek-on-ssms